# Labeled and Unlabeled break, continue in C# or C++

Tags: java, c#, c++

I have a good experience in C# but now i works on java project so i take a tour in java features. I haired about Labeled and Unlabeled break (it available also in JavaScript) it's really good feature and it shorten a lot of time to use labeled break in some cases.

my question is, what is the best alternative of labeled break in C# or C++, with a look i think we can use goto keyword to go out from any scope, but i don't prefer it. I tried to write a code in Java to search in number in two dimensional array using labeled break it's very easy:

```
public static void SearchInTwoDimArray() 
{
// here i hard coded arr and searchFor variables instead of passing them as a parameter to be easy for understanding only.
    int[][] arr = {
            {1,2,3,4},
            {5,6,7,8},
            {12,50,7,8}
    };

    int searchFor = 50;
    int[] index = {-1,-1};
    out:
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j] == searchFor)
                {
                index[0] = i;
                index[1] = j;
                break out;
                }

        }
    }
    if (index[0] == -1) System.err.println("Not Found!");
    else System.out.println("Found " + searchFor + " at raw " + index[0] + " column " + index[1] );
}
```

When i try to do that in C#:

1. it's possible as i say before to use goto
2. i used flag instead of label:

   ```
       public static void SearchInTwoDimArray()
   {
       int[,] arr = {
           {1,2,3,4},
           {5,6,7,8},
           {12,50,7,8}
   };

       int searchFor = 50;
       int[] index = { -1, -1 };

       bool foundIt = false;

       for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
           {
               if (arr[i, j] == searchFor)
               {
                   index[0] = i;
                   index[1] = j;
                   foundIt = true;
                   break;
               }

           }
           if(foundIt) break;
       }
       if (index[0] == -1) Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
       else Console.WriteLine("Found " + searchFor + " at raw " + index[0] + " column " + index[1]);
   }
   ```

so is it the only efficient way to do that or there is a known alternative in C# and C++ of the labeled break or labeled continue?

Comment: Voted to close - opinion based.  A good compiler should optimize the code to break out of loops regardless of the common layouts.  The best way is the one that is the most readable and safest.

Comment: A labelled break is only marginally better than a plain 'goto', so *if* you like coding like this in Java you should have no problem with a C# 'goto'.

Comment: I prefer the goto to the extra flag. Imitating **labeled break** is perhaps the last case in which a goto is still useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than a goto, it may be better just to restructure your C# logic something like

```
public static String SearchInTwoDimArray()
{
    int[,] arr = {
        {1,2,3,4},
        {5,6,7,8},
        {12,50,7,8} };
    int searchFor = 50;
    int[] index = { -1, -1 };

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (arr[i, j] == searchFor)
            {
                 index[0] = i;
                 index[1] = j;
                 return("Found " + searchFor + " at raw " + index[0] + " column " + index[1]);
            }

        }

    }
    return("Not Found");
    // Console.ReadLine();  // put this line outside of the function call
}
```

Comment: I am happy with this, but returns from the body of a double loop tend to bother the same people who never use `goto`.